# How to watch a server's HDD activity (opened files and simple hddled) in SSH?

Tags: linux, monitoring, console, hard-drive

I'd like to see if a hard disk is being actively used right now (a hddled-like indicator) and what particular files are being accessed. How can I achieve this in command line with SSH?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the usage by using a tool like [iotop](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/iotop/).  You can see a list of open files by using the command [lsof](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/lsof/).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to iotop/lsof that was already mentioned, some other options include [nmon](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-analyze_aix/), [iostat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat), or [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/).  See this post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469159/an-htop-like-tool-to-display-disk-activity-in-linux) or this other question here on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/9428/how-can-i-monitor-hard-disk-load-on-linux).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to run the command through ssh and not just ssh directly to the machine. The command from ssh will look some thing like this:

`ssh <hostname> lsof <options>`

If you need this to run as root from a script, slightly fancy use of sudo and ssh keys should get you no requirement for a password. But be careful slightly to fancy use of sudo and ssh keys can just up and give anybody root access to your box.